# Excel 2010 VBA - Get the left side cell of the current cell?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

My sheet is like this:

```
| A | B | ...
---------
| 1 | a | ...
---------
| 2 |   |
---------
| 3 |   |
---------
| 4 | b |
---------
```

And I want this as my output:

```
| A | B | ...
---------
| a |   | ...
---------
| 2 |   |
---------
| 3 |   |
---------
| b |   |
---------
```

So I'm looping column `B` and whenever there's a value in `B` then I should replace the corresponding one in `A`

So far I've tried like this:

```
Sub LoopRange()

   Dim rCell As Range
   Dim rRng As Range

   Set rRng1 = Sheet1.Range(A1, A1000)
   Set rRng2 = Sheet1.Range(B1, B1000)

   For Each rCell In rRng2.Cells
       If Not IsEmpty(rCell.Value) Then
          'SET THE VALUE OF THIS rCELL TO THE CELL THAT'S LEFT OF IT  
   Next rCell

End Sub
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this without loops utilising `Evaluate`:

```
Sub QuickKill()
Range("A1:A1000") = Application.Evaluate("=IF(B1:B1000<>"""",B1:B1000,A1:A1000)")
End Sub
```

Comment: It runs the VBA equivalent of normal `IF` test on the 1000 cells. It is equivalent to putting `=IF(B1<>"",B1,A1)` into `A1` and copying down to `A1000` **without** causing the circular reference that would happen if you tried this with a standard formula.

Comment: can you help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402178/excel-2010-vba-map-column-data

Answer (score 5):

Solved it! But check out **brettdj**'s answer. I guess it's better.

```
Sub LoopRange()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range

    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("B1:B1000")

    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(rCell.Value) Then
            rCell.Offset(0, -1) = rCell.Value
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
For each c in range("a2"a8")
c.value= c & " " & c.offset(,1)
next c
columns(2).delete
```

The Above code will combine the two columns

```
c.value= c.offset(,1)
```