# Map column data to matching rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a sheet like this:

```
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | ...
---------------------------------
| a | 1 |   | b | 2 |   | c | 7 |
---------------------------------
| b | 2 |   | c | 8 |   | b | 4 |
---------------------------------
| c |289|   | a | 3 |   | a |118|
---------------------------------
| d | 6 |   | e | 3 |   | e |888|
---------------------------------
| e | 8 |   | d |111|   | d |553|
---------------------------------
```

I want the sheet to become like this:

```
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | ...
---------------------------------
| a | 1 | 3 |118|   |   |   |   |
---------------------------------
| b | 2 | 2 | 4 |   |   |   |   |
---------------------------------
| c |289| 8 | 7 |   |   |   |   |
---------------------------------
| d | 6 |111|553|   |   |   |   |
---------------------------------
| e | 8 | 3 |888|   |   |   |   |
---------------------------------
```

Col A, Col B and Col G have letters which are unique, and in the col next to it it has weights.

To make it even more clear,

```
| A | B |
---------
| a | 1 |
---------
| b | 2 |
---------
| c |289|
...
```

are the weights of a,b,c... in **January**

Similarly `| D | E |` are weights of a,b,c... in **July** and `| G | H |` are weights of a,b,c... in **December**

I need to put them side-by-side for comparison, the thing is they are NOT in order.

How do I approach this?

**UPDATE**

There are thousands of a,b,c, aa, bb, cc, aaa, avb, as, saf, sfa etc.. and some of them MAY be present in January (Col A) and not in July (Col D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

**code**

```
Sub Squeeze()
[c1:c5] = Application.Index([E1:E5], Evaluate("IF(A1:A5<>"""",MATCH(A1:A5,D1:D5,0),A1:A5)"), 1)
[d1:d5] = Application.Index([H1:h5], Evaluate("IF(A1:A5<>"""",MATCH(A1:A5,G1:G5,0),A1:A5)"), 1)
[e1:h5].ClearContents
End Sub
```

*Explanation of first line*

```
 Application.Index([E1:E5], Evaluate("IF(A1:A5<>"""",MATCH(A1:A5,D1:D5,0),A1:A5)"), 1)
```

- The `MATCH` returns a VBA array matching the positions (5) of `A1:A5` against `D1:D5`
- `INDEX` then returns the corresponding values from `E1:E5`

So to use the *key* column of A1:A100 against M1:100 with values in N1:100

```
Application.Index([N1:N100], Evaluate("IF(A1:A100<>"""",MATCH(A1:A100,M1:M100,0),A1:A100)"), 1)
```

Comment: Oh My God, you're brilliant at this!

Comment: Major credit goes to a gentleman called Rory Archibald who first showed me the `Evaluate` array trick.

Answer (score 0):

Extend as necessary: Sort D:E by D ascending, sort G:H by G ascending, delete G,F,D,C. If you want VBA, do this with Record Macro selected.

Comment: there are thousands of a,b,c, aa, bb, cc, aaa, avb, as, saf, sfa etc.. and some of them MAY be present in January (Col A) and not in July (Col D) - Sorting won't give me necessary result :(